# Deleting a node from a Binary Search Tree

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

My Binary Search Tree program doesn't seem to be deleting anything when I call the deleteNode method. The BST is built perfectly, its just deleting the node part that doesn't work. I call it from my main like this:

```
System.out.println("Please enter a number you would like to delete from the tree");
    temp = reader.nextLine();
    try {
        int numTemp = Integer.parseInt(temp);
        TreeNode treeTemp = bst.deleteNode(numTemp, bst.getRoot());
        bst.setRoot(treeTemp);
    }
    catch(Throwable e){
        System.err.println(e);
    }
    bst.printInBST(bst.getRoot());
```

In my BinarySearchTree class I implement my deleteNode methods as following:

```
public TreeNode deleteNode(int x, TreeNode temp){
    if(temp != null){
        if(x > (int)((Integer)temp.getValue())){
            temp.setLeft(deleteNode(new Integer(x), temp.getLeft()));
        }
        else if(x < (int)((Integer)temp.getValue())){
            temp.setRight(deleteNode(new Integer(x), temp.getRight()));
        }
        else if(temp.getLeft() != null & temp.getRight() != null){
            TreeNode temp2 = new TreeNode(temp.getRight().getValue());
            while(temp2.getLeft() != null){
                temp2 = temp2.getLeft();
            }
            temp = temp2;
            temp.setRight(remove(temp.getRight()));
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
public TreeNode remove(TreeNode temp){
        if(temp.getLeft() != null){
            temp.setLeft(remove(temp.getLeft()));
            return temp;
        }
        else {
            return temp.getRight();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are not handling the

case 1:  where the deleting node is a leaf node

case 2:  where the deleting node has just 1 child

---

the else if part should be something like this.

```
else if( temp.getLeft() != null && temp.getRight() != null ) // Two children
{
      temp.setValue( findMin( temp.getRight() ).getValue());
      temp.setRight ( deleteNode( temp.getValue(), temp.getRight() );
}
else
     temp = ( temp.getLeft() != null ) ? temp.getLeft() : temp.getRight();

return temp;
```

---

The findMin method is to find the inorder successor of the node to be deleted.

```
private TreeNode findMin( TreeNode t )
{
        if( t == null )
            return null;
        else if( t.getLeft() == null )
            return t;
        return findMin( t.getLeft() );
}
```

---

I hope this answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Writing legible code makes bugs easier to spot - both by yourself and others. A first step is choosing more expressive variable names than `temp`, `temp2`, and `treeTemp`.

Also, it is really not neccessary to do `new Integer(x)` to assign a method parameter of type `int`. Simply writing `x` instead has the same effect, is faster at runtime, and makes it easier to spot the code that matters.

As for bugs, the first one I see is:

```
TreeNode temp2 = new TreeNode(temp.getRight().getValue());
```

That creates a copy of the TreeNode. Changing that copy won't affect the original node. Also, the copy probably doesn't have `left` or `right` set, since you only pass the `value` to the constructor. I wonder why think you need a copy? After all, you don't create one here either:

```
deleteNode(new Integer(x), temp.getRight())
```

Next, as Sashwat points out, if the node to delete has less than 2 children, your code doesn't do anything, as none of the conditions in `deleteNode` matches.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure if this is your only problem, but should:

```
else if(temp.getLeft() != null & temp.getRight() != null)
```

actually be:

```
else if(temp.getLeft() != null && temp.getRight() != null)
```

i.e. you only have one & for the "and" operation when you should have two?

Answer (score 0):

```
  public class BSTNode {
  …

  public boolean remove(int value, BSTNode parent) {
        if (value < this.value) {
              if (left != null)
                    return left.remove(value, this);
              else
                    return false;
        } else if (value > this.value) {
              if (right != null)
                    return right.remove(value, this);
              else
                    return false;
        } else {
              if (left != null && right != null) {
                    this.value = right.minValue();
                    right.remove(this.value, this);
              } else if (parent.left == this) {
                    parent.left = (left != null) ? left : right;
              } else if (parent.right == this) {
                    parent.right = (left != null) ? left : right;
              }
              return true;
        }
  }
```